# Neo4J server is not stopping

Tags: database, server, neo4j

DBMS failed to stop: undefined

The following logs and troubleshooting guide may help you diagnose the issue:
Desktop logs
Neo4j DBMS logs
Troubleshooting guide

Comment: Oops, I got the solution,  I had to restart my pc.

Comment: Same question with Neo4j Desktop 1.4.7 and DBMS 4.3.1. I am creating a helloworld project and cannot stop it.